# How do I make a bash function to create multiple named directories and then organize their included files by extension?

Tags: linux, bash, piping

I'm trying to create a bash function script that will allow me to create multiple directories with the names below. Every time I run it i does both echos fine but in between it says (mkdir: ./: File exists), but the are no files there already. What am I doing wrong? I should add that the script is another folder in my root directory named bin just to be clear.

```
   #!/bin/bash

    echo "Creating directory categories"

    function make_folder 
    {
        cd -; cd content; sudo mkdir ./$1
    }

    make_folder "documents"
    make_folder "other"
    make_folder "pictures"
    make_folder "media"

    echo "Directories have been made"; cd -
    exit
```

Update: I'm also trying to organize files by extension into their corresponding folders (i.e. .jpg into pictures, .doc into documents, .gif into media, etc).

```
   ext="${filename##*.}" #set var ext to extension of files

   find ./random -name | #find and list all files in random folder
                         #pipe results of find into if statement

   if ext == ["jpg"; "jpeg"; "png"] #move ".jpg", etc to new destination
        then
          mv /path/to/source /path/to/destination

   elif ext == [".gif"; ".mov"] #move ".gif", etc to new destination 
        then
          mv /path/to/source /path/to/destination
   else                         #move other files into to new destination
          mv /path/to/source /path/to/destination
   fi
```

Comment: you don't have $folder variable, replace with $1.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm new to bash so i figured it was something simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash, arguments to functions are accessed via variables $1, $2, etc.

As written in the question the variable `$folder` hasn't been set and so the `mkdir ./$folder` command will expand to be `mkdir ./`, which exists (hence the error message)

The following minor tweak would help:

```
function make_folder 
    {
        folder=$1
        cd -; cd content; sudo mkdir ./$folder
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing you meant `local folder=$1`, not `$folder=$1`, as the latter is a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an efficient, idiomatic reformulation of your code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Note how I'm using *single* quotes for all strings that should be
# treated as *literals* (strings that need no interpolation).
echo 'Creating directory categories'

make_folders()
{
    # Create subfolders, prefixed with `./content/`
    # "${@}" is the array of all arguments (parameters) and parameter 
    # expansion `/#/./content/` replaces (`/`) the beginning of each parameter
    # (`#`) with string './content/', which effectively prepends './content/` to
    # each argument.
    sudo mkdir -p "${@/#/./content/}"
}

# Change to the root folder here; e.g.:
# Without an argument, `cd` changes to the current user's home folder.
# (This won't usually fail, but it's always a good idea to check.)
cd || { echo 'Error.' >&2; exit 1; }
# Alternatively, do nothing to start with the *current* dir,
# or use `cd -- "${BASH_SOURCE%/*}"` to change to the folder in which 
# the script resides.

make_folders 'documents' 'other' 'pictures' 'media' || { echo 'Error.' >&2; exit 1; }

echo 'Directories have been made'
```

As for what you've tried:

- `cd -` changes to the *previous* directory, whatever it may have been, as stored in `$OLDPWD`; in a script, `$OLDPWD` it is initially *unset*, causing the `cd` command to fail with error message `cd: OLDPWD not set`.

  - It's best to avoid changing the current dir. altogether, or to do it once at the beginning of the script, or to scope the change to a subshell.
  - [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) points out in a comment that if you do use `cd`, you should always check its exit code to see if it succeeded, so as to ensure that subsequent commands really operate on the intended files/directories.
- `./$folder` references variable `$folder`, which you've never set; as mentioned, arguments passed to a function are accessible as `$1`, `$2`, ..., or collectively as *array* `$@`.

  - Additionally, as a general rule, you should always *double-quote* variable references (unless you specifically want the shell to split them into words by whitespace and subject them to globbing (pathname expansion)); in your case, this would have meant `"./$folder"`.
- Since both user-defined functions and `mkdir` support passing *multiple* arguments, it's more efficient to define the function accordingly and pass the names of all folders to create *at once*.

Comment: An additional note about using `cd` in scripts: if you do use it, you should *always* check its exit status, because if a `cd` fails, subsequent commands will do be running from a directory other than the one you expected. That, and relative file references can get confusing.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Great tip, thanks - I've updated the answer.